# Galaxy A51 stuck in ODIN mode after OTA update

Tags: samsung, data-recovery, boot-loop, boot, odin

Samsung Galaxy A51 received an OTA update last night - installed it, auto-restarted, loaded the Samsung welcome page, then loaded a bright blue screen with:

```
ODIN MODE (AVB fail)
SUPER: Build-id does not match with the reference
(SUPER): 71281625R, (BOOTLOADER): 66118624

Downloading...
Do not turn off target
Do not disconnect USB cable during the software update!
Volume down key + side key for more than 7 secs : cancel (restart phone)
```

And a barcode in the bottom-right corner of the screen.

Followed the instructions to restart (vol & side key) but just returned to the same ODIN page. Same when restarting when connected to the PC. PC says it can't recognise the USB device when it's connected.

I'm not interested in using the phone again, I just want to retrieve photos and any other data from it if possible.

I'm a relative novice, but I can follow instructions if anyone has a solution? Thanks!

Comment: This should work without losing any data. https://youtu.be/ITHXrsIexkg?si=Aq7vnvY4yRfRpDUS

Comment: Thank you @A51 all fixed!  Took me a while to work out which CSC I needed but main thing is I've been able to retrieve all the photos and files!